# How to make the same space between words in python

Tags: python

I have two arrays with words. One is the words before processing, the second is after.

```
before = ['screen', 'properly', 'salients', 'spoiled', 'respond']
after = ['screens', 'properly', 'salient', 'spoil', 'responds']

print("Before", "|", "After")
print("\t|\t")

for i in range(5):
  print(before[i], "\t|\t", after[i])
```

After processing, I want to display it in a line, separated by "|". Like "before  |  after".
However, words are with different lengths and therefore the division with a tab turns out to be really ugly

```
Before | After
    |   
screen  |    screens
properly    |    properly
salients    |    salient
spoiled     |    spoil
respond     |    responds
```

Comment: Don't use tabs, pad with spaces according to the length of the longest string on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` to find the highest length, then adjust the column size accordingly:

```py
before = ['screen', 'properly', 'salients', 'spoiled', 'respond']
after = ['screens', 'properly', 'salient', 'spoil', 'responds']

# collect the header and content in a single list
words = [["before","after"],["",""],*zip(before, after)]

for before, after in words:
  # align the before to at least the length of the longest word
  print(f"{before:<{max(len(i[0]) for i in words)}} | {after}")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZBBDoIwEEXjlhO4nHQDGExcGqInaVigTGOT2jZtjSJyEjds9FCexlKU4MLV_N-Z_9L8-1PX7qBk1z1Oji3Xr9l8h0wZhC3Q2O4NoowziLVRGo2oe21LwVE6G7RWXGDVS4PeyCouopI5NBOA_UMYAZO49fnorExlewAlw29IRgKUFBkl3vi5uHKdDNsMwjL1SW_h5xG4hIDLIwBtuHQJI81wkm-aY3lJBMqE01WRQp_mYyJtW7hBEzAtSYeCPj19-3oD)

Answer (score 0):

```py
before = ['Before','','screen', 'properly', 'salients', 'spoiled', 'respond']
after = ['After','','screens', 'properly', 'salient', 'spoil', 'responds']

padding = len(max(before+after, key = len))
for i in range(5):
  print(before[i].rjust(padding), "|", after[i].ljust(padding), '|')
```

prints something along the lines of

```
  Before | After    |
         |          |
  screen | screens  |
properly | properly |
salients | salient  |
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate that solves most of tabular data issues.

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

before = ["screen", "properly", "salients", "spoiled", "respond"]
after = ["screens", "properly", "salient", "spoil", "responds"]

# many table styles: https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate#table-format
print(
    tabulate(
        zip(before, after),
        headers=("Before", "After"),
        tablefmt="fancy_grid",
    )
)
```

outputs

```
╒══════════╤══════════╕
│ Before   │ After    │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│ screen   │ screens  │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│ properly │ properly │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│ salients │ salient  │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│ spoiled  │ spoil    │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│ respond  │ responds │
╘══════════╧══════════╛
```